# How do you vertically center absolute positioned text w/o declaring container size and w/o JS?

Tags: html, css

I initially had vertically centered text using the table/table-cell display method, which worked great.  The problem came when I switched to a percentage height for the container and used a block level image (sibling to the text in question) to set the size of the container.  I can no longer get the absolutely positioned text to equal the container height without declaring a static container size.  Obviously this is simple to solve with JS, but I'd prefer not to go that route.

I'm also using picturefill.js to serve images, so using the image as a css background isn't an option (unless anyone has suggestions to make it work).

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rHZdQ/

And here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="tile">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#">
    <div class="header-container">
      <h2>title</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tile {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.header-container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 199;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Centering Text in an Absolutely Positioned Image Overlay Using CSS

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400">
    </div>
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="panel">
            <h2><span>percentage sized div</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS rules:

```
.tile {
    border: 3px solid #555;
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px;
    float: left;
}
.image-container img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header-container .panel {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header-container .panel h2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.header-container .panel h2 span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

The parent/containing block is `div.tile`, and it has two child elements, `.image-container` which is in-flow, and `.header-container` which is absolutely positioned and hence out-of-flow.

Since `.tile` is floated, it shrinks-to-fit the content, which is the image in `.image-container`, with the dimensions determined by the native height and width of the image.

To create the overlay, `.header-container` is absolutely positioned to the top and left of its relatively positioned parent, with 100% width and height which forces it to extend to the containing block (see yellow outline).

Within `.header-container`, create an anonymous table by setting `display: table` to `.panel`, and specify 100% width and height so it extends and fills the `.header-container`.

Finally, define an anonymous table-cell on `.panel`'s nested `<h2>` element, and apply `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` to center the text post horizontally and vertically.

Note that the table-cell will extend the full width and height of the table so if you want to style the text with a border or background, you need to wrap it an inline-block element (the `<span>` in my example).

You can view the code at: **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/hQraK/)**

Comment: First of all, THANK YOU.  I lost most of yesterday wrestling with this.  To add clarity for anyone dealing with this, the key to Marc's answer is using a four level nested structure for (respectively) absolute positioning, table display, table-cell display and the text itself.  Floating the top level container may or may not be necessary depending on your site layout.

Comment: You are very welcome!  This was a good problem to delve into. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

Does your `.header-container` need to be `width:100%`? Can you use pixels instead?

If you use pixels and you do the following, then it will center it:

```
.header-container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

Basically, `margin-left` has to be equal with half the `width` and a  minus in fornt and then `left:50%`

UPDATE:

After informing me that it has to be only with percentage, the Jquery would be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var minus = '-';
    var headerwidth = $(".header-container").width();
    $(".header-container").css('margin-left',minus+(headerwidth/2)+'px');
    $(".header-container").css('left','50%');

});
```

Comment: I need to use percentage based width and height, thus the issue.  Thanks for answering though!

Comment: I see. Well sorry then but the only solution I see is jQuery

I will update my answer above.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  If you read the original post, it states that I need to center the text **vertically**.  Horizontal centering is almost never a problem in CSS.  I also stated "w/o declaring container size" in the title, and expounded this point in the explanation text.  I specifically am looking for a non-javascript solution.

Comment: The jQuery solution may be helpful to others and it would be worthwhile to actually finish it as a working demo fiddle.  Visitors can then see both the CSS solution and a jQuery solution and pick the one that is most applicable.  I would encourage you to finish your answer (also, center vertically too).  Up vote for effort!!