# Remaking fixed grid to a responsive grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid, responsive-design

I have implemented this fixed grid: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/UxzCa/1. There are two requirements:

- images should fit into a ***square*** *`card`* div (width/height can be different);
- card dimensions shouldn't be fixed.

As for dimensions it is possible to implement using jquery and recalculate widths/heights on `window.resize` event. Are there alternative ways?

Comment: If the card dimensions are not fixed, how many cards per line do you want, or do you want to set a min-width to the card?

Comment: I've been thinking about putting from 6 to 8 cards. Or recalculate widths dynamically at any given N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial solution that takes care of the image aspect-ratio issue and the fixed-width issue.

For the fixed-width of the grid, set the `width: auto` and this will allow the floats
to wrap to as many lines as required:

```
.grid-row {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The images need to scale with height if they are portrait (height/width > 1) or width if they are landscape (height/width < 1).

Define the following classes:

```
.table-cell img.portrait {
    height: 100%;
}
.table-cell img.landscape {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and then use the following jQuery method to set the correct class based on the aspect ration of each image:

```
$('.table-cell').each(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    aspectRatio = image.height()/image.width();
    if (aspectRatio > 1) 
    {
        image.addClass('portrait');
    }
    else
    {
        image.addClass('landscape');
    }
});
```

**[See Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gn45K/)**

### Footnote

It may be possible to make the `.card` elements responsive and maintain their aspect ratio using some CSS techniques similar to the ones presented in the following question:

[How do you vertically center absolute positioned text w/o declaring container size and w/o JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722779/how-do-you-vertically-center-absolute-positioned-text-w-o-declaring-container-si)